# Errorr en cálculo Java Applet

Tags: java, gráficas

Necesito correr este applet pero al querer calcular no me calcula, ¿cuál será mi error? Soy nuevo en la programación.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class AppletGuia2 extends Applet implements ActionListener {
       TextField tfEstatura,tfPeso;//entradas de texto
       Label lEstatura,lPeso;//label de los textos de entrada
       Button boton;
       double resultado;//variable para mostrar el resultado
       //método constructor,donde se crean los objetos a dibujar en el applet
       public AppletGuia2() {
//Damos la instruccion que no se usará ningun layout para poder dibujar con setBounds
              this.setLayout((null));
              //setBounds(posicionx, posiciony, ancho, alto)
              lEstatura= new Label("Estatura (mt): ");
              lEstatura.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
              lPeso= new Label("Peso (kg): ");
              lPeso.setBounds(20, 40, 100, 20);
              tfEstatura = new TextField(); 
              tfEstatura.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 20);
              tfPeso = new TextField();
              tfPeso.setBounds(120, 40, 100, 20);
              boton = new Button("Calcula");
              boton.setBounds(120,80,100,20);
              //agregamos los elementos a la pantalla
              add(lEstatura);
              add(lPeso);
              add(tfEstatura);
              add(tfEstatura);
              add(tfPeso);
              add(boton);
               boton. addActionListener(this); // se le añade al boton la facilidad de
              // ser escuchado

        }
        //método paint en el cual se pone lo que se quiere dibujar
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            double peso = Integer.parseInt(tfPeso.getText());
            double estatura = Integer.parseInt(tfEstatura.getText());
            resultado = peso / ( estatura * estatura );
               this.setSize(300, 300);
               g.drawString("Su Indice de Masa corporal es = "+resultado, 20, 120);
//dibuja el cuadrado
        }
        // método para realizar las opciones al oprimir un botón
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Von Storm, Cual es el error que te da?? , si lo publicas en la pregunta, mas personas te podrían ayudar.

Comment: Debes recalcular el peso, estatura cada vez que se clickea el botón. Eso lo realizas implementando tu método `actionPerformed`. Como ayuda, deberia ser muy parecido al metodo `paint`